# Not able to display in Template the foreign key using ListView

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

> I'm trying to display a photographic session with all of it photos, so I have the session name in one model and I have the pictures in
>   another model linked by a foreign key. I'm not able to display it in
>   the HTML I'm not sure if I'm using the ListView get_context_data
>   correctly and I'm certainly sure the the html code is not correct but
>   I have not found how to do it.

**views.py**

```
class SessionPictures(generic.ListView):

    model = PostSession
    template_name = 'photoadmin/gallery.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SessionPictures, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['picture'] = Images.objects.all()
        return context
```

**models.py**

```
class PostSession(models.Model):
    session_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.session_name)


class Images(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(
        PostSession, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures')
```

**html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}


<h2>Images</h2>
<ul>
    {% for session in object_list %}
    <li>{{ session.session_name }}</li>
    <ul>

        <li>{{session.picture_set.all.url}}</li>

    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>



{% endblock %}
```

I'm expecting this:

Woods

- picture1.url
- picture2.url
- picture3.url

Beach

- Picture4.url
- picture5.rul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already defined `related_name="images"` in Images model, so, `session.images_set` attribute won't work with `PostSession`.

```
class Images(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(
        PostSession,related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Instead, use `session.image.all` in template(FYI: it returns a queryset, so you need to iterate through it to get the image object):

```
{% for session in object_list %}
    <li>{{ session.session_name }}</li>
    <ul>
        {% for i in session.images.all %}
            <li> i.picture.url </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

More information on reverse relation can be found in [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/relations/).